# Envío de Correo tipo reunión. Envía la hora actual

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando enviar un correo electrónico con un calendario ics como adjunto, logro que lo envié, sin embargo en la hora no logro que envié los parámetros de inicio y fin. Me está enviando la reunión entre el rango de la hora actual.

Este es el código

```
 public void SendMail(string tomailid)
 {
     try
     {

         string Body = "Cuerpo del Correo";

         //Attach Calender  
         string schLocation = "Conference Room";
         string schSubject = "Seguimiento de Importaciones";
         string schDescription = "SGC - Seguimiento Orden de Compra";

         System.DateTime schBeginDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtfechaseguimiento.Text);
         System.DateTime schEndDate = schBeginDate.AddMinutes(30);

         //PUTTING THE MEETING DETAILS INTO AN ARRAY OF STRING  

         String[] contents = { "BEGIN:VCALENDAR",  
                          "PRODID:-//Flo Inc.//FloSoft//EN",  
                          "BEGIN:VEVENT",  
                          "DTSTART:" + schBeginDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("ddMMyyyy\\THHmmss\\Z"),  
                          "DTEND:" + schEndDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("ddMMyyyy\\THHmmss\\Z"),  
                          "LOCATION:" + schLocation,  
                     "DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:" + schDescription,  
                          "SUMMARY:" + schSubject, "PRIORITY:3",  
                     "END:VEVENT", "END:VCALENDAR" };

         /*THE METHOD 'WriteAllLines' CREATES A FILE IN THE SPECIFIED PATH WITH  
        THE SPECIFIED NAME,WRITES THE ARRAY OF CONTENTS INTO THE FILE AND CLOSES THE 
         FILE.SUPPOSE THE FILE ALREADY EXISTS IN THE SPECIFIED LOCATION,THE CONTENTS  
        IN THE FILE ARE OVERWRITTEN*/
         System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Server.MapPath("Sample.ics"), contents);






         //string name = Session["UserName"].ToString();  
         MailMessage myMailMessage = new MailMessage();
         myMailMessage.To.Add(tomailid);

         myMailMessage.From = new MailAddress("is@kaa.net");
         myMailMessage.Subject = "You have 1 scheduled Meeting";
         Attachment mailAttachment = new Attachment(Server.MapPath("Sample.ics"));
         myMailMessage.Attachments.Add(mailAttachment);


         myMailMessage.Body = Body;

         mySmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
         mySmtpClient.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
         mySmtpClient.Port = 587;
         mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
         mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
         mySmtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user@domain.net", "password", "user@domain.net");
         //mySmtpClient.TargetName = "STARTTLS/smtp.office365.com";

         System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s,
                         System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
                         System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
                         System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
         {
             return true;
         };


         mySmtpClient.Send(myMailMessage);

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
     }
 }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Coloca un breakpoint en `Random rnd = new Random();` copia lo que hay en `contents` edita la pregunta y le agregas ese dato :D

Comment: Listo, en el control de hora y fecha seleccioné las 11 am

Answer (score 1):

A ver, el siguiente código utiliza un memorystream en lugar de un archivo para subir, esto se hace para evitar conflictos que 2 usuarios estén enviando el mismo adjunto.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.To.Add("johndoe@user.com");
message.From = new MailAddress("info@company.com", "Company, Inc");
message.Subject = "subject";
message.Body = "emailbody";
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
...
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string DateFormat = "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ";
string now = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString(DateFormat);
sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
sb.AppendLine("PRODID:-//Compnay Inc//Product Application//EN");
sb.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
sb.AppendLine("METHOD:PUBLISH");
foreach (var res in reg.Reservations) {
  DateTime dtStart = Convert.ToDateTime(res.BeginDate);
  DateTime dtEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(res.EndDate);
  sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
  sb.AppendLine("DTSTART:" + dtStart.ToUniversalTime().ToString(DateFormat));
  sb.AppendLine("DTEND:" + dtEnd.ToUniversalTime().ToString(DateFormat));
  sb.AppendLine("DTSTAMP:" + now);
  sb.AppendLine("UID:" + Guid.NewGuid());
  sb.AppendLine("CREATED:" + now);
  sb.AppendLine("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:" + res.DetailsHTML);
  //sb.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:" + res.Details);
  sb.AppendLine("LAST-MODIFIED:" + now);
  sb.AppendLine("LOCATION:" + res.Location);
  sb.AppendLine("SEQUENCE:0");
  sb.AppendLine("STATUS:CONFIRMED");
  sb.AppendLine("SUMMARY:" + res.Summary);
  sb.AppendLine("TRANSP:OPAQUE");
  sb.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
}
sb.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
var calendarBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(calendarBytes);
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, "event.ics", "text/calendar");
message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Código extraído de: https://esausilva.com/2016/11/17/create-ical-ics-files-in-c-asp-net-mvc-several-methods/